# Periodically, the text 'busted!' is typed in to my computer. Is this a virus, trojan, annoyance device?

Tags: virus, trojan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Happens randomly, most noticeable when I have the cursor focused on a text box/field. HijackThis, MalwareBytes and a bunch of others find nothing. My keyboard isn't wireless, but my mouse is, and the mouse adapter (logitech) is compatible with keyboards. Could someone be pranking me?

Comment: Post your OS and a Screenshot of the text please.

Comment: There is a virus called the "busted virus" i'm trying to dig up some info on it, but i'm willing to bet this is it.

Comment: Here you go: http://wiw.org/~meta/vsum/view.php?vir=247 if it is indeed that, its from 1992 so must be pretty easy to remove by now

Comment: @sirex that is old school research. +1

Comment: Win7, x64 with Norton Security Suite (courtesy of Comcast). It isn't a 1992 virus - it's actually sending keystrokes to whatever app I have open (most often visual studio or notepad). Screen-captures are irrelevant.

Comment: i cant find a new virus that has similar properties. If you get no joy with AV products I'd suggest backup data you care about and just nuke it from orbit / reinstall.